# Apache embeded FTPS (Mina) issue on Java11+

Tags: tls1.2, java-11, apache-mina, apache-ftpserver

I have a very simple Java 8 project (FTP server), which uses Apache FTPS (Mina) server library (v. 1.1.1). It is as simple as the following code:

```
    ListenerFactory factory = new ListenerFactory();
    factory.setPort(2221);
    
    // SSL config
    SslConfigurationFactory ssl = new SslConfigurationFactory();
    ssl.setKeystoreFile(new File("keystore.jks"));
    ssl.setKeystorePassword("password");
    // set the SSL configuration for the listener
    factory.setSslConfiguration(ssl.createSslConfiguration());
    factory.setImplicitSsl(true);

    FtpServerFactory serverFactory = new FtpServerFactory();
    // replace the default listener
    serverFactory.addListener("default", factory.createListener());
    
    //Configure user manager and set admin user
    PropertiesUserManagerFactory userManagerFactory = new PropertiesUserManagerFactory();
    userManagerFactory.setFile(new File("users.properties"));
    UserManager userManager = userManagerFactory.createUserManager();
    if (!userManager.doesExist("admin")) {
        BaseUser user = new BaseUser();
        user.setName("admin");
        user.setPassword("password");
        user.setEnabled(true);
        user.setHomeDirectory(USER_HOME_DIR);
        user.setAuthorities(Collections.<Authority>singletonList(new WritePermission()));
        userManager.save(user);
    }
    serverFactory.setUserManager(userManager);

   // start the server
   FtpServer server = serverFactory.createServer(); 
   server.start();
```

Needed maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ftpserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>ftpserver-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

to simply create a self-signed Keystore:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias self-signed -keystore keystore.jks -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

I followed the official guide to write this code: https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/embedding_ftpserver.html

If I compile and run this code with Java 8, my FTPS server works perfectly fine, I can reach this server through localhost:2221 and with username "admin" and password "password". From my FTP client (I use Filezilla), I can see that the TLS connection was successfully established.

If I compile and run the same code with Java 11+ (I tried with 11 and 15), I see the following message in my FTP client, and the directory listing fails:

```
Status:         Connecting to 127.0.0.1:2223...
Status:         Connection established, initializing TLS...
Status:         Verifying certificate...
Status:         TLS connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status:         Logged in
Status:         Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Command TYPE okay.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,225,229)
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 File status okay; about to open data connection.
Error:          Received TLS alert from the server: User canceled (90)
Error:          Could not read from transfer socket: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Response:   226 Closing data connection.
Error:          Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

And this is the full application log (with VM parameter ):

```
2021-03-30 22:59:09.304  INFO 10557 --- [           main] com.example.ftp.demo.DemoApplication     : Starting DemoApplication using Java 11.0.7 on Kara's-MBP with PID 10557 (...)
2021-03-30 22:59:09.306  INFO 10557 --- [           main] com.example.ftp.demo.DemoApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-03-30 22:59:09.601  INFO 10557 --- [           main] com.example.ftp.demo.DemoApplication     : Started DemoApplication in 0.487 seconds (JVM running for 1.046)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-03-30 22:59:09.886 CEST|SSLCipher.java:438|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
2021-03-30 22:59:09.966  INFO 10557 --- [           main] o.a.ftpserver.impl.DefaultFtpServer      : FTP server started
2021-03-30 22:59:24.393  INFO 10557 --- [ NioProcessor-3] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : CREATED
2021-03-30 22:59:24.395  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-1] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : OPENED
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1B|NioProcessor-3|2021-03-30 22:59:24.443 CEST|SSLCipher.java:1840|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE-countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1B|NioProcessor-3|2021-03-30 22:59:24.444 CEST|SSLCipher.java:1994|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE-countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1B|NioProcessor-3|2021-03-30 22:59:24.472 CEST|SSLCipher.java:1994|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE-countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1B|NioProcessor-3|2021-03-30 22:59:24.490 CEST|SSLCipher.java:1840|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE-countdown value = 137438953472
2021-03-30 22:59:24.493  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-1] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : SENT: 220 Service ready for new user.

2021-03-30 22:59:24.501  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-1] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : RECEIVED: USER admin
2021-03-30 22:59:24.503  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-1] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : SENT: 331 User name okay, need password for admin.

2021-03-30 22:59:24.503  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-1] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : RECEIVED: PASS *****
2021-03-30 22:59:24.505  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-1] org.apache.ftpserver.command.impl.PASS   : Login success - admin
2021-03-30 22:59:24.505  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-1] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : SENT: 230 User logged in, proceed.

2021-03-30 22:59:24.505  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-2] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : RECEIVED: OPTS UTF8 ON
2021-03-30 22:59:24.506  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-2] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : SENT: 200 Command OPTS okay.

2021-03-30 22:59:24.506  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-1] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : RECEIVED: PBSZ 0
2021-03-30 22:59:24.506  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-1] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : SENT: 200 Command PBSZ okay.

2021-03-30 22:59:24.507  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-2] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : RECEIVED: PROT P
2021-03-30 22:59:24.508  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-2] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : SENT: 200 Command PROT okay.

2021-03-30 22:59:24.508  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-1] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : RECEIVED: OPTS MLST size;modify;type;
2021-03-30 22:59:24.509  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-1] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : SENT: 200 Command OPTS okay.

2021-03-30 22:59:24.509  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-2] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : RECEIVED: CWD /
2021-03-30 22:59:24.511  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-2] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : SENT: 250 Directory changed to /

2021-03-30 22:59:24.511  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-2] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : RECEIVED: TYPE I
2021-03-30 22:59:24.512  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-2] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : SENT: 200 Command TYPE okay.

2021-03-30 22:59:24.512  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-1] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : RECEIVED: PASV
2021-03-30 22:59:24.513  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-1] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : SENT: 227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,226,235)

2021-03-30 22:59:24.513  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-2] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : RECEIVED: MLSD
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1D|pool-3-thread-2|2021-03-30 22:59:24.526 CEST|SSLCipher.java:1840|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE-countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1D|pool-3-thread-2|2021-03-30 22:59:24.527 CEST|SSLCipher.java:1994|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE-countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1D|pool-3-thread-2|2021-03-30 22:59:24.528 CEST|SSLCipher.java:1994|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE-countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1D|pool-3-thread-2|2021-03-30 22:59:24.529 CEST|SSLCipher.java:1840|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE-countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|ALL|1D|pool-3-thread-2|2021-03-30 22:59:24.533 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:994|Closing output stream
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1D|pool-3-thread-2|2021-03-30 22:59:24.533 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:466|duplex close of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1D|pool-3-thread-2|2021-03-30 22:59:24.534 CEST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1372|close the SSL connection (passive)
2021-03-30 22:59:24.535  WARN 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-2] org.apache.ftpserver.impl.PassivePorts   : Releasing unreserved passive port: 58091
2021-03-30 22:59:24.535  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-2] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : SENT: 150 File status okay; about to open data connection.

2021-03-30 22:59:24.535  INFO 10557 --- [pool-3-thread-2] o.a.f.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter      : SENT: 226 Closing data connection.
```

Additionally, if I remove SSL support from the code, my FTP server works perfectly fine even with Java 11+.

Is anybody of you guys experienced similar issues with Apache FTPS and Java 11+? If yes how did you find a solution?

Comment: Update: Java 11 forces TLS1.3, which I assume causing the problem here

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the problem only when using **FileZilla**. When I use **lftp**, for example, I can connect successfully to the server (after trusting the self signed certificate).

FileZilla seems to have a problem with the jdk's implementation of TLSv1.3. There is a closed (rejected) ticket about this in Filezilla's bugtracker [1].

Also, I can reproduce the problem when using jdk 8. TLSv1.3 was added and enabled in jdk 8 since 8u261-b12 [2].

As a workaround, you can disable TLSv1.3 by using a security property `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` [3] which will force the jvm to choose another algorithm for the security handshake (hopefully it'll be TLSv1.2).(As this is a security setting it's best to discuss it with your security team if you have one in your company).

The security property can be set or updated in jdk's configuration file `java.security`. Its path depends on the jdk and OS you're using.

Usually it is under **$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security** or **$JAVA_HOME/lib/security**.

If you can't find it, you can print its path by launching the jvm with `-Djava.security.debug=all`. You should see the path printed in the startup logs (there may be several files). Look for something similar to the following lines :

```
properties: reading security properties file: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.11.0.9-4.fc34.x86_64/conf/security/java.security
...
properties: reading system security properties file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/java.config
```

You can also update `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` programmatically by adding the two following lines before `ssl.createSslConfiguration()`:

```
String disabledAlgorithms = Security.getProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms") + ", TLSv1.3";
Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms", disabledAlgorithms);
```

Here is the complete program with the added two lines:

```
import org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServer;
import org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServerFactory;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.Authority;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpException;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.UserManager;
import org.apache.ftpserver.listener.ListenerFactory;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.SslConfigurationFactory;
import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.PropertiesUserManagerFactory;
import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.impl.BaseUser;
import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.impl.WritePermission;

import java.io.File;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FtpException {
        String disabledAlgorithms = Security.getProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms") + ", TLSv1.3";
        Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms", disabledAlgorithms);

        ListenerFactory factory = new ListenerFactory();
        factory.setPort(2221);

        // SSL config
        SslConfigurationFactory ssl = new SslConfigurationFactory();
        ssl.setKeystoreFile(new File("keystore.jks"));
        ssl.setKeystorePassword("password");
        // set the SSL configuration for the listener
        factory.setSslConfiguration(ssl.createSslConfiguration());
        factory.setImplicitSsl(true);

        FtpServerFactory serverFactory = new FtpServerFactory();
        // replace the default listener
        serverFactory.addListener("default", factory.createListener());

        //Configure user manager and set admin user
        PropertiesUserManagerFactory userManagerFactory = new PropertiesUserManagerFactory();
        userManagerFactory.setFile(new File("users.properties"));
        UserManager userManager = userManagerFactory.createUserManager();
        if (!userManager.doesExist("admin")) {
            BaseUser user = new BaseUser();
            user.setName("admin");
            user.setPassword("password");
            user.setEnabled(true);
            user.setHomeDirectory("/tmp/admin");
            user.setAuthorities(Collections.<Authority>singletonList(new WritePermission()));
            userManager.save(user);
        }
        serverFactory.setUserManager(userManager);

        // start the server
        FtpServer server = serverFactory.createServer();
        server.start();
    }
}
```

[1] : https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/12099

[2] : https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u261-relnotes.html

[3] : https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.html#GUID-0A438179-32A7-4900-A81C-29E3073E1E90

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the detailed information from @Mohamed.

I just met this issue recently, would like to share the recent testing result. I can reproduce this issue with JDK 16.0.1_64 with FileZilla pro 3.57.1; and JDK 16.0.1_64 with winscp 5.15.5 works fine; and JDK 17.0.1_64 with FileZilla pro 3.57.1 works fine;

Which means using JDK 17.0.1_64 can be a solution.